# list comprehension else nothing python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I trying to use list comprehension to add names that not in list, and i don't know how to use something like `else pass`

```
list_test = []
names = ['Gabriel', 'Lucas', 'Pedro', 'Gabriel', 'Fernando'] # To see the 'Ellipsis' just increase this list

# I know that if i use loop 'for ...' this problem could be solved
# but the original code work like this and i can't change it (this part is only a small slice)

count = 0
while True:
    if count == len(names): # breaks when all names are read
        break

    name = names[count] # Just select each name

    list_test.append(name if name not in list_test else) # i don't know what put in else to pass

    count += 1

print(list_test)
```

I Tried `else ...` but in original code add `'Ellipsis'` to list, in this code sometimes works, but i need a better solution

I want the output is like:
`['Gabriel', 'Lucas', 'Pedro', 'Fernando']`

Someone can help me? ;-

Comment: Does the order matter? Otherwise you can turn it into a set, which has no duplicates by default.

Comment: That usage isn't a list comprehension but just a ternary statement which doesn't make sense if all you're doing is ignoring the append, just have a simple if statement

Comment: Having said that, `list(set(names))` would be far easier way to get distinct values

Comment: @Sayse i know, but i really want to use list comprehension to solve this, even isn't the best way. I will try ```list(set(names))``` tks <3

Comment: You can't do that. it is a conditional expression, not a statement. You cant use expressions like `pass continue return` with it. By the way what you're referring isn't list comprehension

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna i didn't know this, thanks for to explain ^^

Comment: [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep unique values in order you can transform to dictionary keys and back to list:

```
names = ['Gabriel', 'Lucas', 'Pedro', 'Gabriel', 'Fernando']
list_test = list(dict.fromkeys(names).keys())
```

output:

```
['Gabriel', 'Lucas', 'Pedro', 'Fernando']
```

If order does not matter, use a set:

```
list_test = list(set(names))
```

(potential) output:

```
['Lucas', 'Gabriel', 'Pedro', 'Fernando']
```